# Cron job doesn't work, Laravel and cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

For some reason I no longer understand my cron does not work, when I execute the command schedule: run changes are made, however on the server nothing happens, I will explain each step to see if anyone can tell me that I can be doing wrong

this is the code of my command

```
<?php 
namespace App\Console\Commands;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Plan;
use App\Plan_negocio2;
use App\Plan_negocio;
use App\Pagina;
use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

//use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;

class Resaltador extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'res:resaltado';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Verificar Resaltador';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $plan=Plan_negocio::all();
        //$fechaAct=$request->fecha;

        if ($plan) 
        {
            $arrNegocio=[];
            foreach ($plan as $key => $value)
             {  
                //$value->fechafin=strtotime("2017-04-07")-time();

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');   
            $date = new DateTime($value->fechafin);
            $dateHoy=new DateTime();
            //$dat=$dateHoy->getTimestamp();
            $dat=9999999999999999;
            $value->fechafin=$date->getTimestamp();
            //$now = new DateTime();

                //$gene= $date1->format('U') - $now->format('U');


                if ($dat>$value->fechafin) 
                {
                 $negoPlan=Pagina::find($value->negocio_id);
                 $negoPlan->resalta_id=1;
                 $res=$negoPlan->save();

                }

             }
        }

    }

}
```

this, the code of the kernel

```
     <?php 
        namespace App\Console;

        use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
        use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

        class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
            /**
             * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
             *
             * @var array
             */
            protected $commands = [

                //'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
                \App\Console\Commands\Resaltador::class,
            ];

            /**
             * Define the application's command schedule.
             *
             * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
             * @return void
             */
            protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            /*$schedule->command('inspire')
                     ->hourly();*/

                     $schedule->command('res:resaltado')->everyMinute();
        }

}
```

When I execute the schedule: run command everything is fine

[image: databse]

[image: success]

[image]

[image]

But as I say, when I try to activate it from the server I do not understand that it can be wrong, I leave the steps

In the folder 'loupper' is where I have stored laravel, with putty I get the path and assign it to the cron jobs manager in cpanel

[image]

[image]

I don't  have composer on the server, but investigating I read that it is not necessary,However nothing happens, what can I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I just checked and this email has arrived

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: php/home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you missing a space between `php` and `/path/to/artisan` ? The cPanel cron entry seems to think so.

Comment: hi apokrifos, I just checked and this email has arrived
"/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: php/home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan: No such file or directory"

Comment: You need to add a space. `php` `/home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan`

Comment: I left the space but the email is this now
"/bin/sh: php/home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan: No such file or directory"

Comment: this is what I have put 
"php /home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan schedule:run"

Comment: At least now I'm getting another error haha, the error is `<span class="exception_message">Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::everyMinute()</span>`.
Why does this happen? Maybe it's because cpanel forces me to assign the task manually?

Comment: What version of laravel is this? `everyMinute` requires 5.1+

Comment: it's laravel 5.1,I'm trying with `->cron('* * * * *')`, but it seems that the server takes a while to refresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a space between `php` and the path in cPanel

Comment: I left the space but the email is this now "/bin/sh: php/home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan: No such file or directory"

Comment: There is still not a space there. It's `php /home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan`

Comment: thanks dude, At least now I'm getting another error haha, the error is `<span class="exception_message">Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::everyMinute()</span>`

Comment: Why does this happen? Maybe it's because cpanel forces me to assign the task manually?

Comment: You might be running an older version of Laravel. You can use `$schedule->command('res:resaltado')->cron('* * * * *')` instead

Comment: Haha sure man, I see that I have problems because the laravel version I have is 5.1, now I get a message saying `The command defined in" App \ Console \ Commands \ Highlighter "can not have an empty name.` Command I created the variable $ signature, besides that I generated the command with artisan